# access value in an editText from a subclass

Tags: android, variables

I have an edittext onCreate like this:

```
final EditText firstText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
```

I want to get the value of firstText from my subclass:

```
private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener onInitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                isLoaded = true;
                String s = firstText.getText().toString();
            }else{

            }
}
```

Comment: please post the complete scenario of your code ,plus you can make variable `s` global to class then pass it to subclass

Comment: make String s static, public static String s, and keep check while acessing !isEmpty or !=null

Comment: @PavneetSingh As far as I know if he make variable `s` global, he cannot assign new reference to it and to access it in the anonymous class, `s` must be final. 

A better solution would be implement the `OnInitListener` or use interfaces for communication.

Comment: @KartikSharma yup you are right ,  but it's still unclear `i want to get the value of firstText from my subclass`  ,how OP is using sub-class or even the implementation is right, wrong

Answer (score 1):

**first step:** create a `getter` method from your `class` which contains `onCreate` method as:

```
public String getFirstText() {
    return firstText.getText().toString();
}
```

**second step:** call method above from `subClass`:

```
private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener onInitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
                String s = getFirstText();
                // do whatever you want

}
```